# How to add shortcut key on menu in plugin development

Tags: java, maven-plugin-development

I have created "Representations "option on menu .Under Representations there are two pop up submenus .I can add shortcut key for those two pop up sub menus.How to add shortcutkey as(ALT+R)
to my Representations option.My Representation option is not having any command.we can use org.eclipse.ui.binding extension point for only those who are having commands.Now How to add short cut key.Please help me.

Comment: Is this a maven plugin or an eclipse plugin?

Comment: This is eclipse plugin not maven.